# Strapi CMS admin api to create/update webhooks

Tags: .net, strapi

I am using `Strapi CMS` [v4.0](https://docs.strapi.io/) as my content management. I configured the CMS and I want to add new webhooks to the CMS using an API calls. I added the following code to check if there is any webhook created or not. if not so create a new webhook

```
var checkResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync("/admin/webhooks");
if (!checkResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    _logger.LogError("Failed to get existing webhooks. Status code: {StatusCode}", checkResponse.StatusCode);
    return;
}

var webhooksJson = await checkResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var webhooks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Webhook>>(webhooksJson);
var webhookExists = webhooks?.Any(w => w.Url == "{webhookURL}");
if (webhookExists == true)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Webhook already exists.");
    return;
}

// If the webhook does not exist, create a new one
var webhookData = new
{
    name = "webhookName",
    url = "{webhookURL}", // My webhook URL
    events = new[]
    {
    "entry.create","entry.update","entry.delete", "entry.publish","entry.unpublish","media.create","media.update", "review-workflows.updateEntryStage"
},
    enabled = true
};

var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(webhookData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("/admin/webhooks", content);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Webhook created successfully.");
}
else
{
    _logger.LogError("Failed to create webhook: {StatusCode}", response.StatusCode);
}
```

Now I got an error with Status code:

> Unauthorized

however I tested the auth token in another API call and its wokring fine.